# Home Workout: My body has been disfigured. How do I even the both sides?

Tags: bodybuilding

My left chest is smaller 50% than the right. My left back and butt are 30% bigger than the right.

I am right handed so this might have happened. It wasn't so noticeable before but after I started working out at home recently, it's starting to look uneven.

The problem worsened when I started doing push-ups focusing on the left one in order to balance both the chests. Now the chest looks barely even and the left back is growing while the right isn't.

How do I even them out? Any specific technique to workout at home?

Comment: Was it always like this or since you started lifting?

Comment: As per @son15's comment, if they've always been that way, you may have an underlying condition. For myself, due to mild unrealized scoliosis, my arms and legs are slightly different lengths.

Comment: @son15 It's always been uneven but not very noticeable. It's gotten worse as the asymmetry is clearly visible.

Answer (score 1):

Non symmetrical musculature is very common. Everyone has this to some degree. It's usually not something to worry about unless it's serious or it's affecting your body image too much.

In your training you should use more unilateral movements. Things like single arm presses, rows, or lunges, step ups etc. To start with, just be sure to do an extra set or two every workout for the weaker muscle. When doing things one side at a time, do the weaker side first.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but the problem worsened when I started doing push-ups focusing on the left one in order to balance both the chests and now the chest looks barely even and the **left back is growing bigger ** while the right isn't.

Comment: @VivekGhimire, Pushups are still bilateral.  Think about using dumbbells, fixing form, etc.

Comment: @VivekGhimire yes as Berin mentioned push ups are not the best movement to use for that. You need one armed/one legged movements to really focus on one side at a time without exacerbating further imbalances